# how to swap the second row of grid items

Tags: css, grid

help me please, how do i get a result like this in the grid? the result i want - link - img https://ibb.co/XbW025V . here is my code https://jsfiddle.net/o0zjuyqb/1/

```
<div class="container">
     <div class="parent">
       <div class="div1"></div>
       <div class="div2"></div>
       <div class="div3"></div>
       <div class="div4"></div>
       <div class="div5"></div>
       <div class="div6"></div>
      </div>
    </div>
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Questions seeking code help must include the shortest code necessary to reproduce it **in the question itself**  preferably in a **Stack Snippet**. Although you have provided a link, if it was to become invalid, your question would be of no value to other future SO users with the same problem. See [**Something in my website/example doesn't work can I just paste a link**](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/254428/something-in-my-web-site-or-project-doesnt-work-can-i-just-paste-a-link-to-it).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do this by using `grid-column: span 2;`

```css
.grid {
  display: grid;
  grid-auto-flow: dense;
  grid-template-columns: 250px 290px 290px 250px;
  grid-template-rows: repeat(2, 280px);
  gap: 40px;
}

.grid div {
  background: grey;
}

.grid div.wide {
  grid-column: span 2;
  background: green;
}
```

```html
<div class="grid">
  <div class="wide"></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div class="wide"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: all three columns are of different width in the given reference..

Comment: yeah it was just to show the general idea, I've updated it with the right sizes.

Comment: thank you, I would replace it with grid-auto-rows: 280px;